# Openlayers 3 Geolocation, Center the postion onclick

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3

I have a button to activate the geolocalisation. Once i click on it, I want to activate the geolocalisation also i want to zoom on the position but only when i click the button. My problem is the first click, the tool returns an undefined position and I have to click a second time to get the position. I want to ask the community if you have a workaround for my problem.

See the JsFiddle i have create: http://jsfiddle.net/alex_caron88/m6xbv0dt/8/

Here the important part of the code:

```
// activate geolocate device and get the zoom on the position
var geolocateBtn = document.getElementById('geolocate');
    geolocateBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        geolocation.setTracking(true); // Start position tracking
        map.on('postcompose', render);
        // while (geolocation.getPosition() == undefined){
            // console.log("while = " + geolocation.getPosition())
        // }
        map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition()) 
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the ol3-examples. I set the view.setCenter within the 'change:position' event, not in 'postcompose'. Maybe that will fix it.
I didn't checked your code, so cant really tell if this will fit to your requirements.

```
var geolocateme = new ol.Geolocation({
  projection: view.getProjection()
});
geolocateme.on('change:position', function () {
  var coordinates = geolocateme.getPosition();
  positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
  view.setCenter(coordinates);
})
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that if the user decides to go to another place on the map, with each change of position, it will be returned to the position of geolocation. This is what I want to avoid and what I want to do is to simply allow it to regain its position by clicking on the geolocation button

Comment: you could add geolocateme.setTracking(false); after the setCenter... and set this value back on true when the user clicks the button again. Or use a checkbox and use the value true false for the tracking. Like 
geolocateme.setTracking(this.checked);